# Help. php-mbstring : Depends: php7.0-mbstring, Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: phpmyadmin

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php-mbstring : Depends: php7.0-mbstring but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Have you tried to run `sudo apt install php7.0-mbstring`?

Comment: $ sudo apt install php7.0-mbstring 

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.0-mbstring : Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.4-7ubuntu2) but 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt install  php7.0-common php7.0-mbstring php-mbstring`

Comment: Ok let me post an answer for you to accept, :7{).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you needed to install them in a sequence so any dependencies will be taken care, so the way aught to have been:

```
sudo apt install php7.0-common php7.0-mbstring php-mbstring
```